# Function doesn't work within another function, but the inner function's code works when directly inside outer function

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I'm a newbie to JavaScript and I'm trying to shorten my code by declaring a function for code that I use it repeatedly within another function, but that new inner function doesn't work.

This program is intended to increase the number by 1 upon each press of the button, and then output to the HTML based on the "FizzBuzz" rules: Numbers divisible by 3 are replaced with "Fizz", numbers divisible by 5 are replaced with "Buzz", and numbers divisible by both are replaced with "FizzBuzz".

Here is my original code, which functions as intended:

```js
const fuzzCont = document.getElementById("fizzbuzz-cont")

const fuzzPlusButton = document.getElementById("plus-button")
fuzzPlusButton.addEventListener("click", fuzzPlus)

let fuzzCount = {
Numb: 0,
Fizz: 3,
Buzz: 5,
}

fuzzCont.innerText = fuzzCount.Numb

function fuzzPlus() {
  fuzzCount.Numb = fuzzCount.Numb + 1
  
  if (fuzzCount.Numb % fuzzCount.Fizz === 0 && fuzzCount.Numb % fuzzCount.Buzz === 0) {
  fuzzCont.innerText = "FizzBuzz"
  } else if (fuzzCount.Numb % fuzzCount.Fizz === 0){
  fuzzCont.innerText = "Fizz"
  } else if (fuzzCount.Numb % fuzzCount.Buzz === 0){
  fuzzCont.innerText = "Buzz"
  } else {
  fuzzCont.innerText = fuzzCount.Numb
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="fizzbuzz-cont">Placeholder Text</div>

<button id="plus-button">+1</button>
```

The above code includes the same calculation multiple times, which I'm trying to eliminate by creating a function for that calculation that would replace said calculation in the subsequent code, but with this new function implemented the code isn't actually replacing any of the numbers with "Fizz"/"Buzz"/"FizzBuzz"... and I have no idea why.

Here's the code with this issue:

```js
const fuzzCont = document.getElementById("fizzbuzz-cont")

const fuzzPlusButton = document.getElementById("plus-button")
fuzzPlusButton.addEventListener("click", fuzzPlus)


let fuzzCount = {
  Numb: 0,
  Fizz: 3,
  Buzz: 5,
 }

fuzzCont.innerText = fuzzCount.Numb


function fuzzCalcDivide(fuzzCheck) {
  fuzzCount.Numb % fuzzCheck === 0
}

function fuzzPlus() {
  fuzzCount.Numb = fuzzCount.Numb + 1
  
  if (fuzzCalcDivide(fuzzCount.Fizz) && fuzzCalcDivide(fuzzCount.Buzz)) {
  fuzzCont.innerText = "FizzBuzz"
  } else if (fuzzCalcDivide(fuzzCount.Fizz)){
  fuzzCont.innerText = "Fizz"
  } else if (fuzzCalcDivide(fuzzCount.Buzz)){
  fuzzCont.innerText = "Buzz"
  } else {
  fuzzCont.innerText = fuzzCount.Numb
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="fizzbuzz-cont">Placeholder Text</div>

<button id="plus-button">+1</button>
```

I tried declaring the `fuzzCalcDivide` function within the `fuzzPlus` function, didn't fix the issue.
I tried declaring variables for Fizz and Buzz which aren't object properties and replacing the object properties in the if-else statements with those variables (e.g `let fuzzFive = 5`& `else if (fuzzCalcDivide(fuzzFive))`), didn't fix the issue.
I tried looking up previous posts on Stack Overflow for a solution, and couldn't find any applicable question/answer (but apologies if I missed such question/answer).

Comment: `fuzzCalcDivide` doesn't return anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `fuzzCalcDivide` is not returning the result of the comparison. You should just return the result of the operation as follows:

```
function fuzzCalcDivide(fuzzCheck) {
  return fuzzCount.Numb % fuzzCheck === 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fuzzCalcDivide is not returning anything

```
function fuzzCalcDivide(fuzzCheck) {
  return (fuzzCount.Numb % fuzzCheck === 0)
}
```